# Open URL from a Windows app in the active browser tab

Tags: c#, url, browser, tabs

I am trying to open a URL in the active browser tab (no new window or tab should be created). I'm able to do this with IE by creating its object and then using the `IE.navigate2()` function but I want to know whether it can be done in a generic way, for all browsers. If not, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I wouldn't do it at all.  You're making an assumption that the task your app is performing is more important than what the user is already doing.  What if the user is, for example, filling out an online tax return?  If your app then launches a page in the existing browser window, they would lose any work they had done.

Also, what happens if the user doesn't have a browser open in the first place?  You're going to have to create a new window in that instance, so why not in all other instances?

The golden rule, in my opinion, is NEVER to hijack anything to user is already doing in an application - there is always another way to do it that won't annoy the user anything like as much.

Comment: I totally agree with ur point of not hijacking things cauz he mite be doin something really imp in d active browser but this doesnt apply in my case as my client is using his pc for my app only.. So it is his requirment which i m trying to fulfill. So is thr ny way to go abt nd doin it..